# Need to combine 2000 variables to a list to use in a for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to use a for-loop to cycle through 2000 iterations in selenium. I have created my permutations and created individual variables for each permutation (used excel to merge them).

I have my variables listed from A1...A2000. I need to get this into a single list so I can use it in a for-loop with my code. They only way I know how is if I separate it with a comma (ex: A1, A2, A3...) but that is unrealistic for 2000 variables.

Any suggestions?

**The variables are listed sequentially like so:**

```
    A1 = ('xpath text')
    A2 = ('xpath text')
    A2000 = ('xpath text')
```

**I am using selenium to web crawl through drop downs**

```
    for i in range(1, 2000):
      xpathlist = [A&i]
      for xp in xpathlist:
        b.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
        click = download.click()
```

Comment: So you have 2000 variables listed in your code, ranging from A1 to A2000 ? Or did I misunderstand something here.

Comment: " I have created my permutations and created individual variables for each permutation (used excel to merge them)" I know this isn't helpful currently, but is your fundamental problem. You should have used a list to begin with. Whenever you see yourself dynamically creating variables numbered from 0 ... N *just use a list*. Anyway, assuming your variables are in the global scope, you can use `global_vars = globals()` and then use `global_vars['A'+str(i)]` to access them, but this is a hack.

Comment: So this issue that I have is that I needed to create a permutation of all drop downs for my web crawl (totally 2000 perms.) The last xpath (as a string) needs to be the download xpath, any permutation with download earlier will not work. So my strategy was to use a permutation function to get all of the combinations and then used excel concatenate to attach to the end (wondering if I could've used an append fx in python now..)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have all those variables in module `foo.py`:

```
import foo
all_vars = (getattr(foo, f'A{i}') for i in range(1, 2000))
```

This has the advantage of not creating the list, but retrieving each value while iterating it. More information about generators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

**Note:** I have used formatted strings (`f''`), which needs python 3.6+, for older versions use `'A{}'.format(i)` or `'A%d' % i`.

Answer (score 0):

*...used excel to merge them...*

I might be reading a little too much into this, but you may be able to bypass Excel with something like:

```py
from itertools import product

NAMES= ('x', 'y', 'z')
VALUES = ('foo', 'bar')

nvs = [f'{n} {v}' for n, v in product(NAMES, VALUES)]
print(nvs)

['x foo',
 'x bar',
 'y foo',
 'y bar',
 'z foo',
 'z bar']
```

Or for permutations (as you stated):

```
from itertools import permutations

VALUES = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux')

perms = [f'{a}/{b}/{c}' for a, b, c in permutations(VALUES, 3)]
print(perms)
['foo/bar/baz', 'foo/bar/qux', 'foo/baz/bar', 'foo/baz/qux',
 'foo/qux/bar', 'foo/qux/baz', 'bar/foo/baz', 'bar/foo/qux',
 'bar/baz/foo', 'bar/baz/qux', 'bar/qux/foo', 'bar/qux/baz',
 'baz/foo/bar', 'baz/foo/qux', 'baz/bar/foo', 'baz/bar/qux',
 'baz/qux/foo', 'baz/qux/bar', 'qux/foo/bar', 'qux/foo/baz',
 'qux/bar/foo', 'qux/bar/baz', 'qux/baz/foo', 'qux/baz/bar']
```

Then you can just iterate over the list `nvs` or `perms`

Comment: Part of my issue is that I have 6 drop downs with a total of 2000 permutations, and the last xpath string has to be download. My strategy was to do the perms in python and then concatenate the download in excel. Doing it this way ended up creating 2000 variables (A1....A2000) There is probably a better way to do the permutations, but I'm not sure how